# How to have access to Azure's Tomcat logs for Java App Service deployment

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, logging

I'm using for the first time Azure to deploy Java Spring Boot applications as a App Service that I used to host on a local Tomcat.

I managed to deploy from Github to Azure directly but I cannot find any logs about the application on platform. On a Tomcat server all the logs are usefull and in my application I'm using Log4j to log into files into Tomcat/logs folder.

Here is my General Settings in the Configuration tab :
[image]

I'm getting lost with all the post that I've found online that I find unclear and also, as I'm just trying Azure right now with the trial offer I might not have access to all functionnality.

Thank you for any help for this !

Answer (score 2):

`Log4j` might not work that wonders like `Application Insights` can do in Azure cloud. I would recommend you to go through this great blog post, that explain step-by-step about migrating your Boot Application to Azure App service and how well you can integrate Monitoring and Logging: [Migrating Spring Java Applications to Azure App Service (Part 2 — Logging and Monitoring)](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/migrating-spring-java-applications-to-azure-app-service-part-2-logging-and-monitoring-3bd7cd0fc1a4)

Their example Spring application uses the `Log4j` logging framework to log required data and traces.
It’s common practice to forward logs to a central logging system (like ELK, Splunk, etc.). Azure Application Insights provides the ability to forward logs to Azure’s central logging system, Log Analytics, with configurable retention periods and the ability to further filter and direct logs to other systems. A common example is to forward logs that are important for security review to SIEM systems.

*First, add AppInsights logging library as shown below:*

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
<version>[2.1,)</version>
</dependency>
```

*Define AppInsights Appender that will forward logs to Azure Log Analytics:*

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\home\\LogFiles\\logs.txt
log4j.appender.aiAppender=com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v2.ApplicationInsightsAppender
log4j.logger.tutorial=DEBUG, file, aiAppender
log4j.logger.com.microsoft=DEBUG, file, aiAppender
```

*As a result you could see all log statements in a Search view for the Log Analytics:*

[image]

If you still want to use `Log4j`, check out [Log with the Azure SDK for Java and Log4j](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/logging-log4j#:%7E:text=As%20mentioned%20in%20Configure%20logging,logging%20frameworks%20such%20as%20log4j.&text=Include%20the%20log4j%20library%20as,properties%20or%20log4j2.).

Comment: Thanks for this ! I'll read the article to try it out.
I'm considering changing the way I'm importing my project into Azure too, right now Github build and deploy directly to Azure but it seems to have some limitation.

Comment: Yupp, you are right. ADO pipelines are better

Comment: What's exactly Azure DevOps pipelines ? I was considering doing to the second method of this tutorial : https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/azure

Comment: So I tried this tutorial to build a API app but I'm getting the error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." when I try to reach the page"

And same thing, can't find any logs no matter how I activated everthing in the settings...

Comment: Pls enable diagnostic logging in App service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Also, try to dpeloy a simple Web API first and then make changes for your code

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Hi, I had already tried to enable diagnostic logging for application logging (Linux). But nothing really usefull showed up. 
Also I can't deploy a Web API as I'm trying to deploy a war and only API app works with that (or I didn't manage to it maybe)

Comment: Log4j can point to the same directory using a Web App ?

Comment: Sorry, I was on inactive since 2 days

Comment: Pls check this out for Diagnostic logging (since you posted an answer on it recently): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows. This can be enabled with free acount.

Comment: Does this answer help? If yes, pls mark it as an answer to help community

Comment: Hi, I answered in my post but still cannot see any error log just traffic or basic trace

Comment: I've switcted to log4j2 but with the basic configuration, it does not write into a file. See here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573788/log4j2-not-creating-any-log-files-java-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to properly deploy a Web App first using the maven azure plugin and it works perfectly. I also saw  the equivalent of the Tomcat's stdout file but as a stream so not very conclusive.

I wanted to enable diagnostic logging but in the free subscription it seeems there is no way to do that.

[image]

Is there a way to try it out ? Thanks !